# DTAttributedTextView not scrolling the contents

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiscrollview

I am using the DTAttributedTextView with a width of 510 and height 710 for ipad.The contents are clipped and i cannot scroll the view to see the contents.I have added the DTAttributedTextView as an IBOutlet.

Comment: As you can see, this was already submitted as an issue on Github:

https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText/issues/509

Comment: Oh that was you, I guess the developer is better off helping you, especially if you don't share code

Comment: NSData *data = [@"some long text" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        
        NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:14.0], DTDefaultFontSize, @"Helvetica", DTDefaultFontFamily, @"black", DTDefaultTextColor, nil];
        NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithHTMLData:data
                                                                              options:options documentAttributes:NULL];
        critiqueDetailsTextView.attributedString = attrString;